# Как использовать хранимую процедуру внутри цикла в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

У меня есть процедура который создает таблицу используя входной параметр

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ppp(in_val in varchar2) is
BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'create table tmp#ppp as
       select * 
       from tmp#table_1 
       where in_v = ''' || in_val || '''' ;
END ppp;
```

`in_val` - это входной параметр, получается при вызове процедуры приходится вводить параметр вручную каждый раз.

Еще есть другая таблица `tmp#table_2` со столбцами `in_val_id` - идентификатор параметра, `in_val_name` - готовые параметры.

Теперь надо с помощью цикла пройтись по таблице `tmp#table_2`, брать оттуда каждый готовый параметр и использовать как входной параметр для процедуры.

Короче надо внутри цикла надо использовать созданную ранее процедуру, как понимаю. Прошу помочь! В *PL\SQL* новичок!!!

Comment: Вы хотите создавать однотипные таблицы в цикле. Это очень странный подход и не понятно, какие задачи принуждают Вас так поступать. Возможно Вам стоит изменить подход, и тогда хватит одной таблицы

Comment: Просто мне по отдельным аттрибутам надо вытаскивать и сравнить две таблицы с помощью minus. можно конечно одним запросом все аттрибуты вытащить, тогда сложно будет разобраться где разница

Comment: Странный подход. Можно вытаскивать и из одной таблицы. Если задача не учебная, то в будущем могут возникнуть проблемы с сопровождением. Лучше стараться избегать такой архитекруты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу видно, что вы с mssql работали. Во первых в оракле нет таких времянок как в mssql. Времянка в оракле создается как обычная таблица (только с пометкой что она временная), которая сама отслеживает сессию и для которой при создании указывается когда в ней удалять записи - по завершении сессии или по завершению транзакции. 
Что касается пройтись по циклу и вызвать для каждой итерации процедуру то это просто:

```
declare 
 in_val  number:=1;
begin
 for i in (

    select
        поле_1
       ,поле_2
    from 
       схема.таблица
     where
        поле = in_val        
 )loop
    схема.имя_пакета.имя_процедуры (параметр_1=>i.поле_1,параметр_2=>i.поле_2);
 end loop;  
end;
```

Только будьте аккуратны, если переменную назвать так же как и поле в таблице, то оракл ничего не скажет а просто поле будет сравнивать, с тем полем имя которого совпадает с именем переменной.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in (select in_val_id  from tmp#table_2) loop
  ppp(x.in_val_id);
end loop;
```